# In JuMP How can we use VariableRef for mapping values?

Tags: variables, optimization, reference, constraints, julia-jump

I am trying to solve an optimisation problem in Julia Jump using Gurobi Pkg.
I have created 2 matrices (A and B) that should be mapped using the 3rd one (Matrix C).

```
@variable(model, lb_C[i,j] <= C[i=1:m, j=1:n] <= ub_C[i,j], integer=true)
@variable(model, lb_X[i,j] <= A[i=1:m, j=1:n] <=  lb_X[i,j])
@variable(model, lb_X[i,j] <= B[i=1:m, j=1:n] <=  lb_X[i,j])

@constraint(model,[i in 1:m,j in 1:n],A[i,C[i,j]]==B[i,j],if C[i,j]!=0 end)
```

but I am getting error:

```
ArgumentError: invalid index: C[1,1] of type VariableRef
```

Can anyone one know how I can solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly index variables like this.

You need to formulate your problem as a mixed-integer linear program.

One technique for this sort of thing are "Indicator constraints"

- JuMP documentation https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/manual/constraints/#Indicator-constraints

```
# Add the constraint x == y if z == 1
model = Model()
@variable(model, x)
@variable(model, y)
@variable(model, z, Bin)
@constraint(model, z => {x == y})
```

The Mosek modeling cookbook has some good modeling tricks:

- https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html